# azure mobile backend - How to Embed linked tables in a one-to-one relationship query?

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

How do I embed a linked reference in the query results of a TableController?

I'm following Adrian Hall's [30 Days of Zumo: Day 26: Relationship Advice](https://shellmonger.com/2016/05/27/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-26-relationship-advice/). As Adrian mentions regarding the one-to-one relationship call to GET tables/TodoItem, "Again, you do the join in code – don’t expect a Tag item to magically be populated in your TodoItem as a linked reference – it won’t happen." Adrian shows how to show linked references in the many-to-many relationship using an expand parameter. How is it done in a one-to-one relationship?

[Adrian's online book](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/relationships/) provides a partial solution to my question but again does not show how it is fully implemented,  "One can easily retrieve the tag information with a LINQ query on the Tag table:"

```
var tag = tagTable.FirstOrDefault(tag => tag.Id.Equals(task.TagId)).Value;
```

Further clarification...
in the 30 days of Zumo, there is a one-to-one table relationship that includes the foreign key in one table as shown below...

```
namespace Mobile.Backend.DataObjects
{
    public class Tag : EntityData
    {
        public string TagName { get; set; }
    }

    public class TodoItem : EntityData
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }

        public bool Complete { get; set; }

        #region Relationships
        public string TagId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("TagId")]
        public Tag Tag { get; set; }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

I'd prefer to keep the foreign key in only one table as shown in Adrian's above example. My primary goals are to embed the tag in the todoItem query results.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a 1:1 relationship between ObjA and ObjB.  You would list the ID of the ObjA in ObjB and the ID of ObjB in ObjA:

```
public class ObjA {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string ObjBId { get; set; }
}

public class ObjB {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string ObjAId { get; set; }
}
```

You then sync both tables for offline usage.  You have two disjoint tables, with Ids of the associated record on the other side of the relationship.  You can use the code you suggested before to get the record on the other side of the relationship.

Comment: Hi Adrian, Your answer deviates from your article in the 30 days of Zumo. There, the one-to-one table relationship only includes the foreign key in one table (see further clarification in my above question). 

I'd prefer to keep the foreign key in only one table. Is this still possible? Also, when you mentioned, "You can use the code you suggested before to get the record on the other side of the relationship", will you please provide an example on how this would work with a TableController? I'm completely lost and embedding the tag in the todoItem query is what I'm really after.

Comment: There are multiple ways of doing the same thing.  Is there a reason why you can't just inject the id?